# Is there a way to access the Matplotlib render method and change it in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is an open ended question. I used a tkinter program to display large sets of data in matplotlib, however I want to make it run faster. So what I thought about is to only update the data in the plot as the user guides their mouse along the x and y axis. Is there a way to override the matplotlib module such that I can render data as the mouse pans across the axis?

For example, I have the current view within y = [0,1], however data exists at y = 2. I can make an algorithm to only pass data within that range in order to pass to the data analytics algorithm for display. I just want to know what possible steps exists in order to dynamically render data in matplotlib instead of having it all there at once. Perhaps using the navigational tool, it can render when the mouse is released? The data is quite large.

Comment: Points (or in general, artists) that are not within the axis limits are not drawn. They hence do not significantly contribute to slowing down anything. It is therefore a bit hard to understand what is asked for here.

Comment: I understand that. However my program has to calculate a large set of line collections before plotting. I want to know a dynamic way such that the lines calculate when I pan across the plot.

Comment: When you calculate things *while* panning, your program will become slower instead of faster.

Comment: In what ways? If I am using real-time data with big data, I don't want the program to max out the memory access with many different components calculating in the background. I'm aware that there's a trade off, however from my experience testing it out, it becomes more laggy while panning when I include all of it.

Comment: Surely you can limit what is pulled into memory if that is the bottleneck; from the question it is not clear if that's really the case. On the other hand, the more you need to calculate during program execution, the longer it takes to create a new view on screen, such that one can easily run into the CPU time being the bottleneck. It's all very vague as it stands. So the more concrete the question becomes, the higher the chances it can be answered.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly the problem. Hence why I want to make it work within a boundary. There's navigation tools with tkinter/matplotlib, and they have a built in package that allows the panning of a graph, however the limit with the program is that it doesn't calculate on panning which is my goal. It has an x/y input, wanting to calculate z so that it will display. I just don't want it to have a permanent delay behind real-time updates.

Comment: It's the same problem that game developers face when having to compute graphics and maximize utility of their application.

Comment: Yes, and that problem is solved in matplotlib because it only ever draws (computes) the parts that are within the visible area. Any additional computation that you would want to add would just slow down drawing.

Comment: You sure about that? I already have a method to limit data input into the plot using LineCollection, which computes graphics within the boundary limits on update. It's just that I can't pan along axis in order to compute it outside the range(or to be more exact, move the boundary).